# Inherited ViewModel passed to UserControl is treated as child ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, method-hiding

I have a View MainWindow.xaml which contains two buttons which are defined in Button.xaml. The button binds to a property `IsVisible` which defines whether the button is visible.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<local:Button DataContext="{Binding ButtonViewModel1}" />
<local:Button DataContext="{Binding ButtonViewModel2}" />
```

Button.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="MyButton" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}">
        <TextBlock>My Button</TextBlock>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

For the Button I have two ViewModels: `ButtonViewModel` and `ButtonViewModelChild`.

`ButtonViewModelChild` inherits from `ButtonViewModel`. Both provide the `IsVisible` property:

ButtonViewModel:

```
public Visibility IsVisible
{
    get
    {
        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

ButtonViewModelChild:

```
public new Visibility IsVisible
{
    get
    {
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

The ViewModel of MainWindow.xaml contains a property `ButtonViewModel1` and `ButtonViewModel2`. These properties look like this:

```
public ButtonViewModel ButtonViewModel1
{
    get
    {
        return new ButtonViewModelChild();
    }
}

public ButtonViewModelChildButtonViewModel2
{
    get
    {
        return new ButtonViewModelChild();
    }
}
```

The button should be invisible if `ButtonViewModel` is used as DataContext for the button and visible if `ButtonViewModelChild` is used.

I assumed that the button which uses ButtonViewModel1 as DataContext gets a `ButtonViewModel` and the other button a `ButtonViewModelChild`. So the first button would not be visible and the second would. Both buttons are visible though. What does WPF do here? Obviously It uses both times the inherited view of the instance. Is there a way to tell WPF to use the return type of the property and not the created-instance type?

I am aware that method hiding is not the best practice. I will probably change the design but I am curious why the result is not as expected.

Comment: Thank your for your quick answer. Then both buttons should not be visible. But they both are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property in a binding path is resolved by reflection, hence it finds the subclass property, regardless of the ButtonViewModel1 property type.

```
public ButtonViewModel ButtonViewModel1
{
    get { return new ButtonViewModelChild(); } // subclass instance
}
```

To avoid that, you would have to return a `ButtonViewModel` instance from the getter:

```
public ButtonViewModel ButtonViewModel1
{
    get { return new ButtonViewModel(); }
}
```

You could as well declare the property as `object`, the binding would still work:

```
public object ButtonViewModel1
{
    get { return new ButtonViewModelChild(); }
}
```

---

Besides that, you should generally not let a UserControl operate an a specific view model (and thus make it dependent of the viel model class). Instead you should declare a `IsButtonVisible` dependency property in the UserControl class, and bind bind it like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Visibility="{Binding IsButtonVisible,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <TextBlock>My Button</TextBlock>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Usage would be:

```
<local:Button IsButtonVisible="{Binding ButtonViewModel1.IsVisible}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem a type error in your getters, **they both return ButtonViewModelChild** viewmodel, when you return ButtonViewModel from ButtonViewModel1 instead of ButtonViewModelChild it's hidden as it should be

Comment: You should take into account that OP is well aware of the fact that both properties return a subclass instance. They are under the impression that the return type of the ButtonViewModel1 property somehow matters.